# Interface as a field in Value Object in DDD

Tags: java, domain-driven-design, value-objects

Does it make sense to create a field in ValueObject as an interface?

I have a field in my aggregate that represents its status.
The state has a natural event-driven flow, but there are times where the state can be set manually.

Currently I have an enum which we treat as a VO, and this contains the flow logic and whether it can change to one state or another.

```
public enum State{
  OK,
  KO,
  PENDING(List.of(KO, OK)),
  CREATED(List.of(KO, PENDING))

  private final List<State> canGoStatus;

  public boolean canGo(Status status){
     return canGoStatus.contains(status)
  }
}
```

The manual update has a number of validations, e.g. from which status it can be set and only a number of statuses are possible, in this case, an OK status cannot be set manually.

As the manually update is a new feature, I was thinking of migrating this VO to a class with a field as an interface, which would be implemented by one enum for the normal flow and one for the manually flow.

```
public interface IState{
  String value();
  boolean canGo(IState status);
}

public enum EventDriveState implements IState{
  OK,
  KO,
  PENDING(List.of(KO, OK)),
  CREATED(List.of(KO, PENDING))

  private final List<EventDriveState> canGoStatus;

  public boolean canGo(EventDriveState status){
     return canGoStatus.contains(status)
  }
}

public enum ManuallyState implements IState{
  CANCEL(List.of(EventDriveState.PENDING, EventDriveState.CREATED)),
  REGISTERED(List.of(EventDriveState.OK)),

  private final List<IState> canGoFromStatus;

  public boolean canGo(IState status){
     return canGoFromStatus.contains(status)
  }
}
```

So I can encapsulate this business logic in the domain, and from the VO itself, generate one implementation or the other, separating in two use cases the two updates (e.g. ManuallySetState, EventDriveSetState).

```
public class State{
  private final IState state;

  public boolean canGo(IState state){
   return state.canGo(state);
  }

  public static IState manuallyState(String state){
    return ManuallyState.valueOf(state)
  }

  public static IState eventDriveState(String state){
    return EventDriveState.valueOf(state)
  }
    
}
```

I'm just starting out and I don't know if this is the purpose of DDD.